# How to call a function from deployed contract to another contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20

I created a basic ERC20 token contract and deployed in rinkeby testnet and I got the contract address now I want to call transfer() function from this deployed contract to another contract without importing the deployed contract in it. Instead of importing I have to use contract address directly. 
Can anyone help me regarding source code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

contract 1 : Already deployed

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract SaveData {
    uint a;
    function getA () public view returns (uint _a){
        return a;     
    }
    function setA (uint _a) public{
        a = _a;     
    }
}
```

contract 2 : To call function of contract 1

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract SaveData {
    uint a;
    function getA () public view returns (uint _a){
    }
    function setA () public{ 
        // you can also ignore functions you are not planning to call
    }
}

contract getData {
    uint b;
    function getAfrom () public view returns (uint){
        SaveData sd = SaveData(0x8c1eD7e19abAa9f23c476dA86Dc1577F1Ef401f5); // address of contract 1 after deployment.
        return sd.getA();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to write the getData contract by using only contract address without rewrite the SaveData contract???

Comment: You don't need to rewrite the whole contract but contract instances are required, as you can see I've only given instance, with name, visibility, parameters and returns, function code is left empty and if you don't want to call certain functions you can omit those too.