# Get value by calling a function from External Smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

There are 2 smart contract

```
contract A {
function abc(string _a) public returns (address) {
    return new B(_a);
 }
}
contract B {
  function xyz(string _a) {
  A a = A(contact address); // interface
  a.abc(_a); 
  }
}
```

How can i get the value of function abc() when i am making a call from function xyz() of contract B which DOES NOT have a return. 
Especially in Remix and also through web3.js 
please guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call a function from deployed contract to another contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66254)

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors. Please provide something that can be compiled and tested, and then explain what it is exactly that you are unable to achieve in it.

Comment: @sp4c3 it is slightly opposite of the question
i am trying to call FROM a function which DOES NOT have a return TO a function which have a return.
So how can i get the return value of the function that i am calling to from the function that does not have a return ?

Comment: @goodvibration this is example code
real code is v big

Comment: @DAOdAppDev what are you gonna do to the returned value from `A.abc()`, you either have to return it, make xyz a return function, Or use it in xyz, for that declare an address variable and store the return of abc in that.

Comment: @Post an MVP (minimal viable program), i.e., the minimal piece of code which readers can reproduce your problem with.

Comment: @sp4c3 thanks for your answer. I think you are right.

Comment: @goodvibration Thanx for you support as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
contract A {
function abc(string _a) public returns (address) {
    return new B(_a);
 }
}
contract B {
  function xyz(string _a) {
  A a = A(contact address);
  address addr = a.abc(_a);
  //do something with addr; 
  }
}
```

Comment: how do i get the value of address when there is no return ?

Comment: If you want the value you have to return it from xyz(), or save it to state to access it with another call. Since that variable is only in memory, it disappears as soon as the call to xyz() completes.